# How is C managing memory in this situation?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, c-strings, strtok

Consider this implementation of `strtok()` in C

```
char *pt;
pt = strtok(line, ":");
if (pt != NULL)
{
    pt = strtok(NULL, ":");
}
```

why doesn't `pt` have to be explicitly allocated memory? Like `pt[128]` or `pt = malloc(...)`? I would have thought the above implementation would segfault. Do I have to worry about deallocation?

Comment: What is `line` in this example? *That* is what needs to be managed.

Comment: This is mostly clear in the documentation of `strtok` (C17 7.24.5.8 or `man strtok`). I think you should rather ask about the parts of that documentation which you don't understand what they mean.

Comment: Anyway the tl;dr is that strtok reorganizes the passed string so that delimiters are replaced by null terminators. Repeated calls iterate through this modified string and returns a pointer to the first character of each sub string, until none remain. And that's about it...

Comment: OT: Another library function, `strdup()`, returns a pointer to allocated memory. The caller is responsible for freeing that pointer. But, `strtok()`, does not allocate any memory that has to be `free()`'d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`line` has to reference modifiable `char` array and most `strtok` implementations are using this memory.

It is the reason why you do not have to provide any additional memory for this operation.

Remember that `line` will be modified (destroyed) during this operation.

`pt` will hold (if not `NULL`) the reference to one of the elements of the array referenced by `line`

Comment: Also worth mentioning that when `strtok` returns a non-null pointer, it points to a location within the string that was originally passed as a non-null first parameter. Subsequent calls with a null first parameter return pointers to locations within the same string.

Comment: Not “most likely.” Definitely. `strtok` is specified to return a pointer to a character in the string, not a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a character array as for example:

```
char s[] = "Hello World";
```

then you can use a pointer that can point to any character of the array. For example this line:

```
char *p = s;
```

that is equivalent to:

```
char *p = &s[0];
```

points to the first character of the string `"Hello World"` stored in the array `s`.

This line:

```
p = s + 6;
```

sets the pointer `p` to point to the substring `"World"` of this string stored in the array `s`.

The function `strtok` splits the passed string to substrings substituting delimiters with zero characters '\0' and just returns a pointer to the selected word.

So for example in this statement:

```
pt = strtok(NULL, ":");
```

the function `strtok` just returns a pointer to the selected substring that is assigned to the pointer `pt`.

By analogy you can consider another function `strchr` that searches whether a specified character is present in a string and returns either the address of the first found such a character or NULL.

```
pt = strchr( line, ':' );
```